# Is there any way to auto increment a field in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to auto increment a stock number for each new item added to the firestore database. (Not using the `push()` method)

The stock number is a controlled number and needs to be **unique** and incremented by 1 every time a new field is added without me having to manually specify the stock number.

Please keep in mind - im a beginner and do not have in depth knowledge of firebase.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily using Cloud Functions

```
// Change '/COLLECTION/{DOC}' to which document do you want to increment the counter when it's created
exports.counter = functions.firestore.document('/COLLECTION/{DOC}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const db = admin.firestore();

  // Change 'counter/ref' to where do you want to increment
  const countRef = db.doc('counter/ref');
  return db.runTransaction(t => {
    return t.get(countRef).then(doc => {
      const counter = (doc.data().counter || 0) + 1;
      t.update(countRef, {counter: counter});
    });
  });
});
```

You can learn more about Cloud Functions here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/